# Как создать файл для хранения большого объема текста не используя базу данных?

Tags: java, android, ресурсы

Файлы `string.xml` и `array.xml` имеют свой лимит на хранение текстовых файлов. Можно ли создать несколько файлов наподобие `array.xml` с другим названием, и как получить затем доступ к самим ресурсам?
Если просто создать файл, например `array2.xml` и попытаться получить к нему доступ, то выдает ошибку.

```
Resources res = mContext.getResources();
String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array2.cat);
```

Может путь как-то по другому нужно прописать? Просто к файлу `array.xml`, все отлично работает.

Comment: создайте в ресурсах папку assets и там можно хранить что угодно. почитайте в доке

Comment: Спасибо я понял

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, но вы не правильно вызываете, вызывайте также, как вызывали, если бы `array` находился в `strings.xml`
Т.е. создаете файл с любым названием в папке `values` с расширением `xml`.
И пишите там массив

```
<string-array name="test">
        <item>test</item>
    </string-array>
```

И вызываете: res.getStringArray(R.array.test);

Comment: Спасибо! Не думал, что так просто)).  А то я уже кастыли стал выстраивать